# Controller method to convert integers to roman numerals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Need help with a method in the controller that will take an integer via a form then convert the integer to a roman numeral and post it back to the web page.

This is my controller so far.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{


    return View();
}
```

```
<h2>Numeral Converter</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Convert numbers to roman numerals</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ConvertController",
                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divInterestDeatils" }))
    {
        <div id="divInterestDeatils"></div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Enter Number to Convert")
                @Html.TextBox("myTextBox")
            </li>
          
        </ol>
        <button>Convert</button>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please describe what the problem is or where you got stuck.

Comment: Put your method in a do while loop.

Comment: i need a method to do the conversion process in the controller that will post the converted number back to the webpage

Answer (score 0):

**Here a working code example :)**
As you see on the method `OnConvertClicked` I convert the input to a number and pass it to the method I created below. This method will return the roman number. After this line of code you can do what ever you want with it e.g show it an the textbox or in a label

```
public void OnConvertClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Button clicked
        try
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(myTextBox.Text); //convert to number
            string romanNumber = ToRomanNumber(number); //Get roman number
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //The user input was not a number...
            myTextBox.Text = "Error"; 
        }
    }
    
    public string ToRomanNumber(int num)
    {
        var listOfNum = new List<int>() {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
        var listOfRoman = new List<string>(){"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};


        var numToRoman = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfNum.Count; i++)
        {
            while (num >= listOfNum[i])
            {
                numToRoman += listOfRoman[i];
                num -= listOfNum[i];
            }
        }
        return numToRoman;
    }
```

Comment: how do i take the input and use the conversion method to return the Roman numeral to the webpage

Comment: @Austincarnage You are welcome. Please edit your question. Code in a comment is unreadable

Comment: i have added the view now to the question